# Array out of bounds for array list comparison

Tags: java

I get the following error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            if(cmp(volume.get(i),volume.get(i+1))>0)
            {
                sorted[i]=list.get(i);
            }
            else 
            {
                sorted[i]=list.get(i+1);
            }
            System.out.println(sorted[i].toString());   
        }
```

Comment: `i+1` is out of bounds in the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This will aware of the out of bounds exception for your work

```
if(list.size() == 1){
    //handle case the list only contain one element here
} else {
    for(int i=0; i < list.size()-1; i++) { //<===list.size()-1
    ...
        if(list.size() == i+1) {
            //handle final loop here (System.out.println(list[i+1]))
        }
}
```

**EDIT**

your work will have IndexOutOfBoundsException again when the `list.size()` is 1

If you want to print all value should check the latest loop and print the value out, or you can wait until all the loop is done then print it out.

**EDIT #2**

Update code

Comment: but then it only compares the first 4

Comment: @JulietCarlos `if(cmp(volume.get(i),volume.get(i+1))>0)` no, each time inside the loop it compare 2 value, which is value index `i` and value index `i+1`; so It will compare whole array. Right?

Comment: but if the array have only one element it will have Index out of bound exception :)

Comment: it will but then it only prints out the first four

Comment: @JulietCarlos Then you should modify your own code with your expected behaviour when it comes to the last element. Just avoid `.get(i+1)` when `i == list.size() - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
list.size();
```

as

```
list.size()-1;
```

list.size(); returns the length of the list. imagine list.size() returns 5. first time of loop there is a value in the list at the index of 0. but at the end i become 5 and there isn't index 5 in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when `i = list.size()-1` , you're trying to access element at `list.size()` and that's causing the Exception.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) //<----------problem 
        {
            if(cmp(volume.get(i),volume.get(i+1))>0) //<----------problem 
            {
                sorted[i]=list.get(i);
            }
```

Simply change `for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)` to `for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++)`

In order to print all the `Strings` just add an additional statement after the `for` loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++)
        {
            if(cmp(volume.get(i),volume.get(i+1))>0)
            {
                sorted[i]=list.get(i);
            }
            else 
            {
                sorted[i]=list.get(i+1);
            }
            System.out.println(sorted[i].toString());   
        }

  System.out.println(sorted[list.size()-1].toString());  //<----to print the last String
```